# How to get fully qualified class name from IResource object?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I have the `IResource` object of a Java class. I need to get the fully qualified class name from this object.

My `IResource.getFullPath().toString()` gives me `/myProject/src/abc/def/Myclass.java`. I want to get `abc.def.Myclass` from it.

How can I get the fully qualified class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you want the fully qualified class name or the fully qualified location in the file system.  I'll mention both:

Class name:

```
((IType) JavaCore.create(iFile)).getFullyQualifiedName()
```

Also, make sure to check for nulls and instanceof.

Resource location:

```
iFile.getLocation()
```

Comment: i want to get the fully qualified class name. I dont have the IFile object with me. I have the IResource, so i did this    ((ICompilationUnit) JavaCore.create(iResource)).findPrimaryType().getFullyQualifiedName() .... this worked

Comment: IResource is an abstract type and IFil eis the concrete type. You must have had access to the IFile or else you could not have created an ICompilationUnit.

Answer (score 1):

```
package abc.def;

public class MyClass {
    public void displayName() {
       System.out.println(this.class.getCanonicalName());// adc.def.MyClass
    };
};
```

Comment: This answer misses the )perhaps unclear) point that the question is about Eclipse APIs.